# inverse image of function and cardinality of resulting set

Tags: functions

Given the set of natural numbers f : $N^{2}$->$N$ and the set of all ordered pairs (a, b) where a and b are natural numbers.

Given a function defined as: f((a,b)) = a + b

find inverse image and cardinality of resulting sets:

part 1: |$f^{-1}$(8)|

part 2: |$f^{-1}$({0,1,2,...,8})|

So for example we have:

$f^{-1}$(3) = {(0,3),(1,2)}

|$f^{-1}$(3)| = 2

Here was my attempt, and it was marked wrong with no feedback.  Any help is appreciated. I wonder if I'm not understanding what is being asked.

Part 1 answer:
$f^{-1}$(8) = {(0,8), (1,7), (2,6), (3,5), (4,4)}

|$f^{-1}$(8)| = 5

Part 2 answer:

|$f^{-1}$({0, 1, 2, …, 8})| = 25

Shown by the following steps:

$f^{-1}$(0) = {(0,0)}

$f^{-1}$(1) = {(0,1)}

$f^{-1}$(2) = {(0,2), (1,1)}

$f^{-1}$(3) = {(0,3), (1,2)}

$f^{-1}$(4) = {(0,4), (1,3), (2,2)}

$f^{-1}$(5) = {(0,5), (1,4), (2,3)}

$f^{-1}$(6) = {(0,6), (1,5), (2,4), (3,3)}

$f^{-1}$(7) = {(0,7), (1,6), (2,5), (3,4)}

$f^{-1}$(8) = {(0,8), (1,7), (2,6), (3,5), (4,4)}

The cardinalities of $f^{-1}$(0) through $f^{-1}$(8) summed are: 1+1+2+2+3+3+4+4+5 = 25.

Comment: Please use MathJax to format your posts. [Here's a tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/742).

Comment: `$f^{-1}$` to get $f^{-1}$. You need to enclose math formulas in dollar signs.

Comment: Much appreciated, fixed formatting.  Any idea on the question?

Comment: What is the domain of the function?  Must $a, b$ be nonnegative integers?  Also, I suspect that you overlooked the fact that $(a, b)$ is an ordered pair, which caused you to miss elements of the inverse image.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I see that it's an ordered pair, but I don't see where I've gone wrong. Wouldn't $f^{-1}(x)$ produce the set of ordered pairs summing to x?  I'm probably confused about what it means to pass a set to this function, like f({0,1,2}).

Comment: You have not fixed the formatting. You are still using ASCII art pretty much everywhere. Format math formulas correctly. f is not the same as $f$; a is not the same as $a$. 0 is not the same as $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you found the inverse images, you missed those ordered pairs $(a, b) \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ in which $a > b$.

For instance, $f^{-1}(3) = \{(0, 3), (1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 0)\}$, so $|f^{-1}(3)| = 4$.

More generally, $|f^{-1}(k)| = k + 1$ since $a$ can vary from $0$ to $k$ over the nonnegative integers.  Thus, the number of elements in $f^{-1}(\{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8\})$ is
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{8} |f^{-1}(k)| = \sum_{k = 0}^{8} (k + 1) = \sum_{j = 1}^{9} j = \frac{9 \cdot 10}{2} = 45$$
where I have used the formula that
$$\sum_{j = 1}^{n} j = \frac{n(n + 1)}{2}$$
in the preceding calculation.

Comment: Now I get it.  Thank you for your help!